# git: How to re-pin commit to different base (no rebase, no merge!)

Tags: git

I'd like to do sth similar to git-rebase but I don't want to re-play changes on different base (introducing changes made in base in my commit). I don't care about base contents. I don't want to merge anything. I'd like to simply create commit A' identical (exactly the same all files) to commit A but connected to another base. Is it feasible?

Comment: You mean like git [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick)? The examples towards the bottom of the docs page are pretty helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "identical"? Part of a commit's identity is who (if any) the parent commit is, which is why rebasing results in nontrivial changes.

Comment: `git checkout another-base; git read-tree A; git commit`

Comment: @PetSerAl: probably want `-u` with `git read-tree`, although it's not critical (you can always `git reset`).

Comment: @PetSerAl - Your solution rocks!; put it as answer, I'll mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (adding answer at top, previous answer after the horizontal line, with more notes): apparently you *do* want to preserve the original tree.

Here's one way to do it with ordinary Git commands.

We'll assume here that you already have the hash ID of the commit you want to copy (or it's the tip of a named branch, or otherwise has a name you can write easily).  First check the output of both:

```
git status
```

to make sure everything is clean (that you won't discard any in-progress work), and:

```
git rev-parse --show-cdup
```

If this prints any `../`-es, `cd` that many `../`-es so that you are at the top of your repository.

Now you need four ordinary Git commands:

```
git checkout target-branch
```

to get onto the branch where you want the copy to land.  Then:

```
git rm -rf .
```

This removes everything, from both index and work-tree.  Then:

```
git checkout <hash-or-name> -- .
```

This re-populates the index and work-tree, using the desired commit as the source of all the files.  (This is like the `read-tree -u` we will see in a moment.)  Finally:

```
git commit
```

to make a new commit using the current index.

Here is another way to do it, per [PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318808/git-how-to-re-pin-commit-to-different-base-no-rebase-no-merge?noredirect=1#comment71791947_42318808).  The main difference is that we don't need to be at the top of the tree:

```
git checkout target-branch
git read-tree --reset -u <hash-or-name>
git commit
```

The `read-tree` operation replaces the current index with the one from the given commit (hash ID or branch name).  The `--reset` part discards unmerged entries if any (there should be none) and is needed to allow the `-u`; the `-u` directs Git to replace all work-tree files with those from the index we are reading-in, and to remove from the work-tree any files that are not in there.  In other words, this is the equivalent of `git rm -rf . && git checkout <hash-or-name> -- .`.  We use one plumbing command (`git read-tree`) instead of two user-facing commands, and we don't need to worry about `cd ../../` or whatever from `git rev-parse --show-cdup`.

---

[chepner's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318808/git-how-to-re-pin-commit-to-different-base-no-rebase-no-merge#comment71791129_42318808) is a key question: a *copy* of a commit, with a different parent link, is a different commit.  So you want to change *something* about the original commit.  The question then is *what, precisely, do you want to change, and what do you not want to change?*

Whether the correct answer is to [use `git cherry-pick`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42318939/1256452) depends on the answer to this question.  So, let's take a look at what is actually in a commit.

Here is a real, actual commit from the Git repository for Git:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree afb30c6559dab43341512cd49dbfc446ac52474a
parent 076c05393a047247ea723896289b48d6549ed7d0
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1487368819 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1487368819 -0800

Git 2.12-rc2

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

What's in the commit is:

- A tree ID: this is the source snapshot.
- Some number of parent IDs, though usually just one: this is something you definitely want to change.
- An author (name, email, and timestamp): who wrote the commit.
- A committer: like author, but the person who put this commit into this repository now.  (This is particularly useful for emailed patches, which is how Linux was done early on, before Git became widespread.)
- The commit message.

If you preserve the original *tree*, you will keep the source snapshot exactly the same as in the commit you copied.  If that's what you want, you cannot use `git cherry-pick` to copy the commit, because cherry-pick is intended for situations where the tree must *change* because of the new base.

The `git cherry-pick` command turns the original commit snapshot into a diff (by comparing it against its parent), then applies the diff to your current commit and makes a new commit from the result.  So this new commit usually has a different `tree` ID.  If that's what you want—it's what most people *do* want—then do that.

It's pretty rare—though not unheard-of—to want to preserve the original tree, though.  To do that, you must either use a bunch of regular user-facing commands, or resort to "plumbing" commands as in [PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318808/git-how-to-re-pin-commit-to-different-base-no-rebase-no-merge#comment71791947_42318808).  Another plumbing command you can use is `git commit-tree`, which lets you write a particular tree ID and set of parent IDs into a new commit you make.  (You can preserve the original author and committer name, email, and timestamp via six Git environment variables—although that particular desire is also rare.)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [R0AMNARMY's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42318808/git-how-to-re-pin-commit-to-different-base-no-rebase-no-merge/42318939?noredirect=1#comment71791059_42318808), you want to use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). Just use the SHA of the original commit in the branch you want to add the given commit.

```
git checkout your-different-branch
git cherry-pick SHA-from-original-commit
```

Comment: Nope, it tries to merge files and reports conflicts:; git cherry-pick master;
error: could not apply 5a0cd5a... commit_4

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to simply create commit A' identical (exactly the same all files) to commit A but connected to another base. Is it feasible?

```
git update-ref refs/heads/another $(
        git log -1 --pretty=%B A | git commit-tree -p another A
)
```

if you've got `another` checked out, follow this with `git reset --hard`.

Comment: It took some time before I understood this. I'm really impressed with this hack.

Comment: It's not really a hack, the other methods show how to winkle sequences of convenience commands meant for other workflows into doing what you want, but they wind up achieving what you want, which this does directly.    Even PetSerAl's lovely method churns the worktree, it usually doesn't matter and I'd do it his way myself working with not-so-very-big commits.